# jqGrid Edit Rules Property Custom Function Regex Validation

Tags: jquery, regex, asynchronous, jqgrid, callback

I'm using the editrules property in jqGrid to call a custom function for validation. I am using a regular expression to validate for a 4 digit year, and I am fairly certain it is correct. Nevertheless, no matter what value is entered when editing the BNFT_YR in the grid, the error message is returned. Is this an asynchronous callback issue? If so, how can it be fixed? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am looking to do? Thank you for the help!

```
    $(function () {
//var x = $('#' + '@(ViewBag.hohupi)').val();

var benyr,
    bnftYearCheck = function (value, colname) {

        var patt = /\d{4}$'/;
        var intRegex = new RegExp(/\d{4}$'/);

        if (colname === "BNFT_YR") {
            benyr = value;
        }

        if (intRegex.test(benyr)) {
            return [true];
        }
        else {
            return [false, "Erorr: wrong input"];
            alert('Incorrect input for BNFT_YR');
        }

    };


$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/Transactions/GetTransactions/",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    /* colNames: ['TransactionID', 'HOH_UPI', 'ICI', 'Run Date', 'Billed QTR', 'Benefit Year', 'Benefit Month', 'Billed Premium', 'Amount', 'Transaction Type', 'Check No.', 'Check Received Date','Entry Date', 'Name on Check', 'Indv Batch Number', 'USER_INIT','Returned Check Date', 'Late Date', 'Final Date', 'Comments'],*/
    colNames: ['TRANS_ID','HOH_UPI', 'ICI', 'Run Date', 'Billed QTR', 'Benefit Year', 'Benefit Month', 'Billed Premium', 'Amount', 'Transaction Type', 'Check No.', 'Check Received Date', 'Entry Date', 'Name on Check', 'Indv Batch Number', 'USER_INIT', 'Returned Check Date', 'Late Date', 'Final Date', 'Comments'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: false, name: 'TRANS_ID', index: 'TRANS_ID', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'HOH_UPI', index: 'HOH_UPI', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'ICI', index: 'ICI', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'RUN_DT', index: 'RUN_DT', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s' } },
        { key: false, name: 'BILL_QTR', index: 'BILL_QTR', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'BNFT_YR', index: 'BNFT_YR', editable: true, editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: bnftYearCheck} },
```

Comment: `/\d{4}$'/` is not correct. `/^\d{4}$/` should be OK. Is `'` a typo? The `^` will make certain you also assert the position at the start of the string and `^` with `$` will ensure the whole string matches the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I altered the regex to your recommendation, but I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
var bnftYearCheck = function (value, colname) {
        if (/^\d{4}$/.test(value)) {
            return [true];
        } else {
            return [false, "Incorrect input for the '" + colname + "' column."]
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Any idea why my code wasn't working?